# How to "flash" an image for a limited time on screen in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, image, timer

I want to take an image and show it on screen (extremely simple website) for 3 seconds. The user would then click a button (I don't need code for these.. just the timer) for whether they recognized the image or not.

It doesn't *have* to be PHP, I've just been using it for most of the application so far. Essentially, I'll have a placeholder "white" image (say 500 px x 500 px) and I'll need the source to change to a different image (easy enough, and would be the same size image).

The issue: I *only* want the image to stay for 3 seconds (exactly) and then reload the "white" placeholder.

Is there a timed function in PHP? Or jQuery, javascript.. anything like that?

There is `microtime` to time out something, but can I set the PHP to *do* something after a specific amount of time?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated! I'd post code but it wouldn't really help to explain the situation...

Thank you!

Comment: something like jQuery's [delay](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) could do this - put the image on the page & then remove it after 3 seconds

Comment: I just included jquery separately because anytime I ask for JS people seem to jump straight to jquery 90% of the time anyway. But essentially it is PhP and AJAX right now. Any input on the timing though? Is there a specific JS function that will enable me to do "a" and then 3 seconds later do "b"?

Comment: @ Rob thank you, that seems like it might work! I'll give it a shot.

Comment: `setTimer` and `setTimeout` would be what you're looking for in plain old javascript (you only need one of them)

Comment: Please! PHP is an abbreviation of "PHP Hypertext Preprocesor", so "PhP" is definitely wrong. I corrected it in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just need a simple javascript [`setTimeout`](http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-settimeout-function-examples/):

```
$('.someImageElement').attr("src", 'someOriginalImageURL')

setTimeout(function(){ 
     $('.someImageElement').attr("src", 'someNewImageURL');
}, 3000); // 3 seconds, adjust as needed
```